# Is NSIS 3.0b1 stable for production usage?

Tags: installation, nsis

I want to try out NSIS install system. On the download page http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Download

There are version 2.46 ( last updated in 2009 ) , and the newer 3.0b1 .

It seems the newer one is in beta and I worry about stability issues.
I wonder if any of you have experience with both versions and willing to comment on them .

BTW, is NSIS still under active maintenance ?

Comment: This is probably a question for the project owners, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Me, I used Inno Setup:  http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

Comment: why choose Inno setup over other options such as NSIS , WIX ... etc  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSIS 3 is basically NSIS 2.46 merged with the Unicode fork + additional bugfixes. Most of the changes are in the compiler and not in the generated installers.

Development is [still active](http://sourceforge.net/p/nsis/code/HEAD/tree/) but don't expect a new release until after Win10 RTM...

Comment: NSIS is always really stable! Even Alpha/beta stages are fine for commercial usage.